# How to create variable pattern matching for database lookup?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql, named-query

I'd like to find a table row where the desired value has the form of `A9-B19-C12-D1`. Thus, variable letters followed by variable digits, devided by `-` each. The length is not fixed, eg it could also be only `A9` or `A9-D1`.

I only care about the letters. Now I have the 4 letters `A, B, C, D` and I want to run a query against `postgres` db that there is an entry in the format above.

Would I do this with the following statement?

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t WHERE t.entry LIKE 'A%B%C%D%';
```

If this is correct: how could I formulate a `NamedQuery` where I could provide the letters as variable parameters?

Comment: Going one step back, I would first ask, why there is one column with a sub structure like that. Depending on the use case, it might make sens e to rethink the table design instead of doing a very inefficient LIKE-query here. Just my two cents :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `SIMILAR TO` with a reqular expression `A\d+(-B\d+(-C\d+(-D\d+)?)?)?`

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(
    name = "finDesiredData",
    query = "select * from mytable t where t.entry SIMILAR TO :ent",
        resultClass = MyTable.class
    )
})
```

I would personally use java `StringBuffer` to concatenate letters into a correct regexp.

Comment: I had it pointed out to me a while ago that `similar to` is technically standard, but not implemented by many other DBs, is transformed to a real regex by Pg, and is generally not great. Better to use a PCRE and the `~` operator to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the `regexp_replace` function in PostgreSQL.
Essentially, using `select regexp_replace('A9-B19-C12-D1', '[0-9]|-', '','g') as letters` returns a string which is `ABCD`.

Similarly, `select  regexp_replace('A9-D1', '[0-9]|-', '','g')` returns `AD`.

Using this information you can write your queries conditioned on the regexp_replace function output. i.e., `SELECT * FROM mytable t WHERE regexp_replace(t.entry, '[0-9]|-', '','g')='ABCD' ;`.

I belive you can index a table column on its function output too - but I will leave that for you to research. You could also look at using [SQL Functions Returning Sets](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/xfunc-sql.html) user-defined functions (I think this is what you mean by named queries).

See [SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/73eed/4)

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, i dont know if i understand your question, but you can set the namedQuery like this:

```
query.setParamter("param1", "%" + 9 + "%");
query.setParamter("param2", "%" + 1 + "%");
```